# Method in dictionary is not defined

Tags: python, dictionary, methods

I have a method in a dictionary as a class attribute;

```
class parentClass(object):
    pass

class childClass(parentClass):
    a = {'meth': my_meth}

    def my_meth(self, var):
        print(var)

inp = input()
# User enters 'meth' 
childClass.a[inp]('test')
```

When I run the program I get the error;

> NameError: name 'my_meth' is not defined

I have read functions are first class citizens in python. How can I assign a method as a value in a dictionary so I can call it later with certain parameters?

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to achieve here. Why are you trying to abstract `my_meth`? What benefit would `childClass.a['meth']('test')` have over `childClass.my_meth('test')` ?

Comment: Anyway, `a` is a class attribute. `self` does not exist when `a` is defined.

Comment: Functionality depends on user input. This is a simplified version as per SO guidelines.

Comment: Fair enough. In this case a bit of over-simplification. It is worth to add your end goal to the question.

Answer (score 2):

```
class parentClass(object):
    pass

class childClass(parentClass):

    def __init__(self):

        self.a = {'meth': self.my_meth}

    def my_meth(self, var):
        print(var)


c = childClass()
c.a['meth']('test')
```

You must define Instance Variables are in **__init__**.

Answer (score 1):

The issue with your code is that you set the **a** as a static variable in the class, but the method in the class is not static and requires **self** parameter.

To solve this, you can make the **a** variable connected with the instances, by setting it in the **__init__** method:

```
class parentClass(object):
    pass

class childClass(parentClass):

    def __init__(self):
        self.a = {'meth': self.my_meth}

    def my_meth(self , var):
        print(var)

childClass().a['meth']('Helloworld')
```

Or the **my_meth** can be made static thus able to call it from the class itself, like:

```
class parentClass(object):
    pass

class childClass(parentClass):


    def my_meth(var):
        print(var)

    a = {'meth': my_meth}

x = childClass.a['meth']("Helloworld")
```

Comment: The issue is actually that the `my_meth` method is defined after the attribute. You moved the attributes of the class below the method and now my code works. Why is this needed?

Comment: All methods need to be defined before they are used, the body of the class is executable (meaning you can run code in it on defining the class), so when you referenced the method, the method was not defined yet, which resulted in the error.